# How can i create an array of objects in which each object has 4 values?

Tags: javascript, api

I want to create an array of objects in which each objects has 4 values. All coming from 4 diferent arrays.The arrays are long.I have no idea on how to do it. It's pretty difficult i think, i have been looking for hours vv'.

```
var local=[F.C Barcelona, Real Madrid, Manchester United.....];
var away=[ Manchester City, PSG, Liverpool....];
var matchDay[2,3,4,5....];
var score=[2-0, 0-1, 2-2...];
```

Comment: While there are some guesses in the answers already, you may want to specify how those objects should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// array to hold the objects
let arr = []
// assuming the four arrays are all the same length
// just pick one to use for the length
for(let i = 0; i < local.length; i++) {
    // create a new object with the 4 fields, one from each array
    // and grab the i'th entry of each array for it
    let obj = {
        local: local[i],
        away:  away[i],
        matchDay: matchDay[i]
        score: score[i]
    };
    arr.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, that was fast. Thank you very much, it looks easy now that you wrote it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but something like this would work.

```
> array1.map(function(item, index){
    return {key1: item,
            key2: array2[index],
            key3: array3[index]
           };
  });
```